# jqGrid displaying different sizes although code is similar

Tags: jqgrid, width

I am working on a jqGrid for two different but similar searches on a site.  The idea is to have two different divs on a popup window.  One that has search fields and the other that displays the results.  The functionality is fine, but the aesthetics are bugging me a little bit.  For one thing the grid comes up as a different size in one.  I use very similar code for both pop up windows however...

```
<div>
    <div id="searchPatient" class="float-left">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#searchByMRN">Search By MRN</a></li>
            <li><a href="#searchByDemographics">Search By Demo</a></li>
            @*<li><a href="#retTable">Return Table</a></li>*@
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_SearchByMRN")
        @Html.Partial("_SearchByDemographic")
        @*@Html.Partial("_RetTable")*@
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper clear-fix float-left" style="height: 1px; padding: 10px;">
        Search For Patient Return Results
        <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
    </div>    
    <div id="resultDiv" style="float: right; clear:both">
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        shrinkToFit: false,
        autowidth: true,
        datatype: 'jsonstring',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: [
                    'Last Name',
                    'First Name',
                    'DOB',
                    'Gender',
                    'EMPIID',
                    'MedipacId',
                    'EPCID'
                    ],
        colModel: [
                    { name: 'Last_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'First_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'DOB', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'GENDER', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'EMPIID', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'medipacId', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                    { name: 'EPCID', width: 145, align: 'left' }
                ],
                ...//unnecessary settings and what-not
)};
)};
```

That code sets up this window...

[image]

```
<div>
    <div id="searchEncounter" class="float-left">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("searchEncounterByCriteria", "SearchEncounter", new { popId = popId }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "SearchPatID" })) {    
            <ul>
                <li>First Name</li>@Html.TextBox("fNameTB", null, new { id = "fNameTB" })
                <li>Last Name</li>@Html.TextBox("lNameTB", null, new { id = "lNameTB" })
                <li>MRN</li>@Html.TextBox("MRN", null, new { id = "MRN" })
                <li>Hospital Fin</li>@Html.TextBox("HospFin", null, new { id = "HospFin" })
            </ul>
        <br />
        <p><input id="sPat" type="submit" value="search For This Patient" class="button" style="float: left; width:auto"/></p>    
    }
    </div>
    <div class="content-wrapper clear-fix float-left"  style="height: 1px; padding: 10px;">
        Search For Encounter Return Results
        <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
    </div>
    <div id="resultDivSE" style="float: right; clear:both">
    </div>
</div>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#list").jqGrid({
                        shrinkToFit: false,
                        autowidth: true,
                        datatype: 'jsonstring',
                        mtype: 'POST',
                        colNames: [
                                   'MRN',
                                   'Hospital Fin',
                                   'First Name',
                                   'Last Name',
                                   'Date of birth',
                                   'Completed Pathway',
                                   'Completed Pathway Reason',
                                   'PCP Appointment',
                                   'Specialist Appointment',
                                   'Admit Date'
                                   ],
                        colModel: [
                                   { name: 'MRN', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Hospital_Fin', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'First_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Last_Name', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Date_of_birth', width: 145, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Completed_Pathway', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Completed_Pathway_Reason', width: 165, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'PCP_Appointment', width: 115, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Specialist_Appointment', width: 125, align: 'left' },
                                   { name: 'Admit_Date', width: 185, align: 'left' }],
                                   ...//superfluous settings that have nothing to do with Grid...
)};
)};
```

That code sets up this window...

Now when debugging using chrome I find out that the widths are being set.  How they are doing it I don't know.  I do know that the element.style {} is being set to

```
element.style {
width: 870px;
}
```

In the second case...
And in the first case it is being set too...

```
element.style {
width: 340px;
}
```

The actual code says

```
<div class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="gbox_list" dir="ltr" style="width: 870px;">
```

in the second case and

```
<div class="ui-jqgrid ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="gbox_list" dir="ltr" style="width: 340px;">
```

In the first case.
I am not sure why this is occuring and how to change it?   What is determining how the width is being set?
Any ideas or advice on how to set widths more consistently?  I want the first grid to be as wide as the second one.

Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have the div of both grids set to `autowidth: true`, the grid should expand to the width of the parent element.  In this case if the parent element of both grids is the same the grids should be the same width.

Another messy option would be to you could specify your columns widths in the first grid to add up to be equivalent widths of the second grid.

For reference you can examine the autowidth property on 
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options

Comment: ShrinkToFit just makes the columns fit within the given sized table width.  Maybe there is something about my first one's div width.

Comment: Do you have autowidth:true on your first(smaller) grid contained by a parent element that is the same width as the containing element of the second(larger) grid?

Comment: I just tested, and if you have the autowidth: true set and the grid is contained by an element with a set width when the grid is created it will expand to that size. Editing my answer to reflect this. So in your case have the grid autowidth property set, and have it contained by an element that is the same size as the second grid.

Comment: Looking right now.  I thought I had both divs set to the same size

Comment: Just checked, both Divs's are about the same size.  I am going to set autoWidth : false and just set the grid size.  While that is not ideal, I can't seem to isolate the one larger element for the time being.

Comment: Did you try setting the width of the container of you first grid: <div class="content-wrapper clear-fix float-left" style="height: 1px; padding: 10px;">
        Search For Patient Return Results
        <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
    </div>

Comment: I haven't actually tried that.  I could do that, but I don't do that with the second one.  Which I find strange.

Comment: I would suggest finding the width of the 2nd grid and then you could set both container's width property to that value.

Answer (score 0):

Try completely removing `searchPatient` and `searchEncounter` divs, and see if something changes. If yes, some differences inside them are affecting the sibling div containing the resultant grids.